# How to sort a set of inline forms in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to find out how to sort inline forms on a particular field created using `inlineformset_factory` in Django. I know it's possible to add an 'order' column which allows the user to specify a sort order, however I already have a field that I want to sort on.

```
LumFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Project, Luminaire, can_delete=True, 
    fields=('lumref', 'lummodel', 'manufacturer', 'lamptype'))
```

generates the formset class.

```
lumformset = LumFormSet(instance=project)
```

generates the formset for the instance.

I want to sort on the lumref field (which is a decimal field).

Comment: (In [11874]) Fixed [#10263](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10263) -- Added a queryset argument to BaseInlineFormSet, normalizing with BaseModelFormSet, and allowing for custom ordering/subsets in inlines. Thanks to Paulo Scardine for the patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can provide a custom queryset to our InlineFormSets:

```
>>> custom_qs = queryset=Book.objects.order_by('-title')
>>> formset = AuthorBooksFormSet(instance=author, queryset=custom_qs)
>>> for form in formset.forms:
...     print form.as_p()
<p><label for="id_book_set-0-title">Title:</label> <input id="id_book_set-0-title" type="text" name="book_set-0-title" value="Les Fleurs du Mal" maxlength="100" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-0-author" value="1" id="id_book_set-0-author" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-0-id" value="1" id="id_book_set-0-id" /></p>
<p><label for="id_book_set-1-title">Title:</label> <input id="id_book_set-1-title" type="text" name="book_set-1-title" value="Le Spleen de Paris" maxlength="100" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-1-author" value="1" id="id_book_set-1-author" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-1-id" value="2" id="id_book_set-1-id" /></p>
<p><label for="id_book_set-2-title">Title:</label> <input id="id_book_set-2-title" type="text" name="book_set-2-title" value="Flowers of Evil" maxlength="100" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-2-author" value="1" id="id_book_set-2-author" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-2-id" value="5" id="id_book_set-2-id" /></p>
<p><label for="id_book_set-3-title">Title:</label> <input id="id_book_set-3-title" type="text" name="book_set-3-title" maxlength="100" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-3-author" value="1" id="id_book_set-3-author" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-3-id" id="id_book_set-3-id" /></p>
<p><label for="id_book_set-4-title">Title:</label> <input id="id_book_set-4-title" type="text" name="book_set-4-title" maxlength="100" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-4-author" value="1" id="id_book_set-4-author" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-4-id" id="id_book_set-4-id" /></p>
>>> data = {
...     'book_set-TOTAL_FORMS': '5', # the number of forms rendered
...     'book_set-INITIAL_FORMS': '3', # the number of forms with initial data
...     'book_set-0-title': 'Les Fleurs du Mal',
...     'book_set-1-title': 'Le Spleen de Paris',
...     'book_set-2-title': 'Flowers of Evil',
...     'book_set-3-title': 'Revue des deux mondes',
...     'book_set-4-title': '',
... }
>>> formset = AuthorBooksFormSet(data, instance=author, queryset=custom_qs)
>>> formset.is_valid()
True
>>> custom_qs = queryset=Book.objects.filter(title__startswith='F')
>>> formset = AuthorBooksFormSet(instance=author, queryset=custom_qs)
>>> for form in formset.forms:
...     print form.as_p()
<p><label for="id_book_set-0-title">Title:</label> <input id="id_book_set-0-title" type="text" name="book_set-0-title" value="Flowers of Evil" maxlength="100" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-0-author" value="1" id="id_book_set-0-author" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-0-id" value="5" id="id_book_set-0-id" /></p>
<p><label for="id_book_set-1-title">Title:</label> <input id="id_book_set-1-title" type="text" name="book_set-1-title" maxlength="100" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-1-author" value="1" id="id_book_set-1-author" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-1-id" id="id_book_set-1-id" /></p>
<p><label for="id_book_set-2-title">Title:</label> <input id="id_book_set-2-title" type="text" name="book_set-2-title" maxlength="100" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-2-author" value="1" id="id_book_set-2-author" /><input type="hidden" name="book_set-2-id" id="id_book_set-2-id" /></p>
>>> data = {
...     'book_set-TOTAL_FORMS': '3', # the number of forms rendered
...     'book_set-INITIAL_FORMS': '1', # the number of forms with initial data
...     'book_set-0-title': 'Flowers of Evil',
...     'book_set-1-title': 'Revue des deux mondes',
...     'book_set-2-title': '',
... }
>>> formset = AuthorBooksFormSet(data, instance=author, queryset=custom_qs)
>>> formset.is_valid()
True
```